How to convert YoloTinyNet to YOLO variables?
I am using the results of detection obtained from a YoloTinyNet model as follows:
results = YoloTinyNet(self._common_params, self._net_params, test=True).inference(image)

To further process them and obtain advanced calculations.
On the other hand I have re-trained a YOLO model and want to use it instead of my old YoloTinyNet model as follows:
model = YOLO('/yolov8/weights/yolov8n.pt')
results = model(source='./image.jpg', conf=0.25)[0]

How to link the two different models is there a way to convert between them?
